# Is it possible to connect a tablet to a computer's localhost server via only USB?

Tags: android

I've found lots and lots of questions around SO asking about connecting tablets to localhost servers, but all of them, question and answers alike, typically involve using hotspots or wifi.

In my current situation, for security reasons, neither the computer nor tablet are allowed to be connected to wifi or cellular connections.

The only connection I have between these two devices is a USB cable.

After looking through plenty of answers, I eventually came across this article:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server

It worked! I was able to access the computer's localhost on my tablet. But it has a drawback: I have to open Chrome and set up the connection manually every time I want to utilize my localhost server. What I want to do is have this port forwarding be permanent, so a user in the future can press a single button in my app and have the server be accessed, without fumbling around in Chrome developer options. (The computer they'll be using will be company-owned)

From there, I looked up Windows port forwarding, and found this article:
http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/

That, however, did not work.

So my question is this: is it possible to, and if so how do I, set up a permanent port forward so my tablet can connect to a localhost server via *only* USB?

Comment: Are you allowed to use USB tethering? You don't need the Internet connection, but just the fact it acts as a network adapter?

Comment: Are you required to connect your tablet with the USB? If not, have you looked into [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)?

Comment: @renyuneyun Would this work with the tablet acting as both the adapter and client, and the computer acting as the server? I haven't looked too much into tethering.

Comment: @mbhargav294 It's the only connection I can figure out between the computer and tablet. It looks like both localtunnel and ngrok require some form of internet connection, which I can't do for security reasons. Correct me if I'm wrong, though!

Comment: @MikeR Why not? Actually your tablet doesn't "act as the adapter" (if I understand it correctly) -- it's your USB ports becoming the adapters. It's a way of using USB and needs the support both from your tablet (which supports, given it's Android) and your computer, just like if you connect your computer and your tablet with a network cable (wire).

Comment: Oh wait... I forgot it's Android. So maybe I'm wrong: I don't know if Android passes your packet through that adapter or not (though I suppose it should). But you can try a simple case and test...

Comment: @MikeR Sorry, both of them requires internet connection

Comment: Potentially useful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_tethering